# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:50343/

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've tried clearing the Chrome Driver from Activity Monitor (Mac) and rerunning the test. It does not work. I've seen this question posted quite often but none of the solutions have worked so far and were all windows based. I am using C# and Visual Studio and a Mac.

**Please see the below Stack Trace:**

```
   at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)

Please see the browser code below: 

**BROWSER.CS**


public enum Drivers
    { 
        Chrome,

    }
    #endregion

    ** Class containing browser driver setup, URL setup, Waits, find element definition, and browser manipulation methods**

    public static class Browser
    {
        #region Driver Instantiation

        static IWebDriver _webDriver;


        public static ISearchContext Driver { get { return _webDriver; } }


 **Returns the driver executable application**

internal static IWebDriver GetDriver(Drivers driver)
        {
            switch (driver)
            {
                case Drivers.Chrome:

                    return new ChromeDriver(@"/Users/wsmith/Projects/Github/folio-quality-assurance/Folio.Selenium.Framework");

                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("I do not know the driver you specified.");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Initialize Browser

**Initializes the webdriver, opens the browser window. This is called in the test fixtures to set up before running the tests**

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            _webDriver = GetDriver(Drivers.Chrome);
            _webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Goto("");
        }
        #endregion

        #region URL
```

Comment: Is Chrome installed on your machine?

Comment: Please add some code on what are you trying to do

Comment: Hello Felipe, yes Chrome is installed on my machine

Comment: Prany I am trying to run a unit test. I was able to run the test see the browser appear and got to the login screen,etc but now I can not get the browser to appear at all.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this? Find the cause of this message?

Comment: In my case with Firefox, the "geckodriver" process was running in the background and I needed to close it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56436485/5755313